# GPS results vary over old and new APIs

Tags: android, gps

Since I'm writing my app in irregular intervals, some of the APIs I use get deprecated by the time I come back. 
Most noticable, is the change in GPS APIs. What confuses me, is that the older APIs seem to give much better results (code will follow).
I'm using a MapView, and also getting GPS coords programmatically with an older method (seperate gps & network provders) and a newer method ("FusedLocation").
I compare both codes' coordinates in google maps, and while the older code (using gps & network provider seperatly) is accurate and steady, the new code (using "FusedLocation") is off by a few hundered meters and not steady, although matches the location that the mapView points to (meaning they are both not that accurate and keeps changing).

So my question is, **which method is the correct one to use**? I thought maybe I was coding wrong the FusedLocation, but since it matches the MapView I ruled this one out.

The old code, using GPS & Network seperatly:

```
public Location getLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                }
            }
                if(isNetworkEnabled) {
                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The new code, using FusedLocation:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    try {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
//some more code
}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

}
```

Comment: *which method is the correct one to use?* ... for what ? for getting the exact position? non of them ... you should setup listener and wait for the provider fix ... seems like yet another "great" code from androidhive ..

Comment: hahaha androidhive rules `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...);
                    if(locationManager != null) { ... }` what is the point of checking if `locationManager` is null right after you called  once of it method ? It is too late ... if `locationManager` would be null than you would get NPE line before ..

Comment: instead of mocking a code which as i stated is rather old, could you refer me to a better coding sample? or try to help me understand why is it actually more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

You should use new API's, FusedLocationProviderAPI includes high accuracy, low battery usage and low memory usage. However android.location is deprecated now.

Check this doc for more info - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see, I (think) I AM using the FusedLocation (check second code). Any ideas?

Comment: I know you are using FusedLocation. I am just answering your question "which method is the correct one to use?" please check documentation provided in answer.

Comment: thanks and sorry, you actually DID try to help. I will try to go over the docs again see why am I getting bad results.